# Windows Phone 8 app randomly crashes with error code -2147220717 (0x80040313)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, crash

I am currently developing a stopwatch and timer app in C#/XAML for Windows Phone 8. While using my app on my phone, I found that it randomly closed out/crashed and that too at different points of use (i.e. I wasn't doing the same thing each time it closed out). While debugging, I found that my app closed out with the following error code in my output window:

"The program '[1100] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313)."

I am very confused as to why this is happening. I tried creating an entirely new solution and moving my code over and I've still been getting the same issue. I have tried using the app on multiple different devices, and the same thing happens (even in the Emulator). Sometimes the app crashes after 5 minutes of use, sometimes it crashes after 30 minutes of use, it's very unpredictable which makes it very hard to find the root of the problem. My app uses the XNA Framework to play an audio sound and the Coding4Fun Toolkit for a TimeSpanPicker control, and besides that there isn't much else that's particularly notable about my app. I have tried removing the playing of the audio file and removing references to the XNA Framework, and the problem persists.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ce4fc333-630e-4ba5-9e20-d26749e8d153/wp75-80-app-random-crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That what David said + 
are you sure that the phone is not running out of memory?

Edit try a windows phone analysis(Alt +F1 | Debug->Start windows phone application analysis)

Comment: i don't know how much optimized it is, but try it, i edited my answer with some more info

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XNA framework in WP project you can get a crash when updating the UI thread. 
You might need to run it through a Dispatcher?

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    // Call your update UI methods here..
});
```

You might also find this post helpful: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/c2751845-cb70-4301-aa1a-796fa1bb8e8c/the-program-241435222-taskhostexe-managed-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0

Comment: UI thread or the User Interface thread is what the user sees, the main thread that handles the Graphics

Comment: have you tried to run the windows phone analysis?
run it until the app crashes

updating the UI thread means that you have more than one thread,
one that displays the data(UI thread) and a background or working thread that does intensive work for you so that the application remains responsive when the working thread has processed some or all of the data and wants to display it you need to send the data to the UI thread("updating the UI thread")

Comment: without any details i can't really point out the issue, but i would say just put breakpoints at lists/collections that are being manipulated with the dispatcher
if one of them increases and you don't want that or has duplicate data you can work on it

Comment: Just to give some closure to this, I found that the problem was not with my DispatcherTimer instead with an AdRotator control I was using in my app. There is a memory leak issue when a certain attribute is set, removing it temporarily fixed the problem for me. Thanks a lot for your help!