# What is this error code all about? -2147220717 (0x80040313)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

My app exits without any exception. the only similar question I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416514/windows-phone-8-app-randomly-crashes-with-error-code-2147220717-0x80040313) but I checked and it doesn't run out of memory and used Dispatcher.

after a few seconds, exits with this output:

> The program '[5700] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220717
>   (0x80040313).

I have no idea what is happening here and even how to reproduce it! Isn't it possible to get list of last called methods in visual studio? debugging step by step doesn't help much.

How to find what causes this error? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VFW_E_CODECAPI_NO_DEFAULT
0x80040313
The specified codec parameter does not have a default value.

For more watch here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375623(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks @JaneksCraft . the problem is that I don't use `DirectShow`, only a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control showing a gif